AI recognition of a hidden corner of a chess board
I need to recognize the 4 corners of a chess board but sometimes one of the corners is hidden by a piece. Should I label the position of it anyway for the training or is it preferable to not train the AI to deduce its position in the case where the local box drawn cannot show effectively the corner ?

Welcome to DS.SE Frank :)  (+1)
Are you expecting there to be hidden corners in the data when the model is put into production ?
